# Reverse commit history

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree to view the commit history of a project. However I'd like to view the commit history from oldest to newest. I want the oldest commit to be at the top, is there any git command which can reverse the order?

Comment: @BJMyers there has to be a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it within the source tree you have to use command line:L

```
git log --reverse
```

Source tree does not support it.